# Реализация алгоритма полный перебор

Tags: java, алгоритм

Помогите пожалуйста сделать алгоритм Brute Force. Который покажет все места в массиве где есть такие же знаки. Например

Ищу: ССQ

Массив знаков: QCCQCQCCCQCCQ

Результат :1,7,10.

```
public class zad1 {
public static char[] toTab(String str) {
    char[] tab = new char[str.length()];
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        tab[i] = str.charAt(i);
    }
    return tab;

}
public static int find(char t[], char w[]) {
    int i=0,j=0;
    int M=w.length, N=t.length;
    while( (j<M) && (i<N) ){
        if(t[i]!=w[j]){ // *
            i-=j-1;
            j=-1;
        }
        i++; // **
        j++;
    }
    if(j==M)
        return i-M;
    else
        return -1; // нечего нету.
}
public static String findTo(char t[], char w[]) {
    String str = "";
    while(find(t, w) > 0) {
        int counter = find(t, w);
        str = str+find(t, w)+", ";
        for(int i=0; i<w.length; i++) {
            t[counter+i] = ' ';

        }
        for(int i=0; i<t.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(t[i]+", ");
        }
        counter = 0;
    }

    return str;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "QCCQCQCCCQCCQ";
    String pattern = "CCQ";

    char[] textTab = toTab(text);
    char[] patternTab = toTab(pattern);


    for(int i=0; i<textTab.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(textTab[i]+", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i=0; i<patternTab.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(patternTab[i]+", ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print(findTo(textTab, patternTab));
}
```

}

Comment: F за такие старания, почти написали собственную функцию

Answer (score 2):

Как-то все слишком сложно у вас... На быструю руку это выглядит так и решается фактически в одну строчку кода:

```
public class Zad1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String text = "QCCQCQCCCQCCQ";
        String pattern = "CCQ";         
        int position = -1;
        while((position = text.indexOf(pattern, position+1))!=-1) System.out.println(position);;
    }

}
```

или так

```
public class Zad1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String text = "QCCQCQCCCQCCQ";
        String pattern = "CCQ";         
        int position = -1;
        while((position = find(text, pattern, position+1))!=-1) System.out.println(position);        
    }

    public static int find(String text, String pattern, int start) {
        for (int i = start; i < text.length(); i++) {
            if (pattern.charAt(0)==text.charAt(i) 
                    && text.length()>=(i+pattern.length())
                    && text.substring(i, i+pattern.length()).equals(pattern)) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Препод требует чтобы алгоритм был без языковых функций типа (sort и find ) и так далее ((( 
может знаете как его написать в таком виде?

Comment: @Hotosho в каком "таком" виде? что конкретно можно/нельзя использовать? я вроде никаких библиотек не подключал и даже никаких импортов не делал. сортировки я тоже не наблюдаю.

Comment: без infexOf - реально это сделать ?

Comment: @Hotosho да легко! ответ изменил

Comment: если бы мог поставил бы пиво!) Весь день потратил на свой код... а оказывается все можно было так сделать))) спасибо )

Comment: @Hotosho тут работы на 3 минуты. проблема в том, что здесь используется substring, а это значит создаются дополнительные объекты - подстроки строки. посему в качестве учебного решения годиться. если нужно что-то подобное в реальном проекте , то indexOf лучше, алгоритм в его сорцах (но там все не так лаконично, как в этом коде). учитывайте это и удачи